# Why is the LIMIT clause not supported in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

It's easy to do pagination using mysql or postgresql by using the LIMIT x,y clause. 
However it is not supported by Oracle or MSSQL. Any insights on why?

I'm not asking for alternatives, I'am aware of them (BTW SQL-SERVER's TOP function doesn't provide the same functionality). I would like to know if there is any technical or licensing reason why the LIMIT x,y clause that it is very useful for web development (pagination) and has a very clean and simple syntax in MySQL and PostgreSQL has complex syntax, sometimes involving subqueries, in other RDBMSs.

Comment: Because they all implement their own variations of the SQL standard. This is one of the biggest differences between all of them.

Comment: I can't answer why, but you can use TOP.

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't ANSI standard SQL, and the standard didn't specify any equivalent functionality. IIRC it's recently been added with syntax similar to but not quite the same as PostgreSQL's, but I don't have references close to hand.

Comment: The clauses LIMIT and OFFSET are PostgreSQL-specific syntax, also used by MySQL. The SQL:2008 standard has introduced the clauses OFFSET ... FETCH {FIRST|NEXT} ... for the same functionality - that is supported by PostgreSQL too.

Answer (score 2):

`MS SQL Server` has `TOP (n)` clause. For `Oracle` you can use `ROWNUM`.
Example from `SQL Server`

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table
```

You can use it also with `ORDER BY clause` as

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table ORDER BY col1
```

from `Oracle`

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

also for `Oracle`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY col1) A WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```